# C# Console Application Dartgame

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm trying to create a dartgame in Console Application with C#.

This is as far as I have gotten atm:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game gameOn = new Game();
        gameOn.PlayGame();
    }

    class Game
    {
        private List<Players> playerList = new List<Players>();

        public void AddPlayers(string name)
        {
            Players names = new Players(name);
            playerList.Add(names);
        }

        public void PlayGame()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Välkommen till Dartspelet! Tryck valfri knapp för att fortsätta...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in antal spelare. Ni kommer också att möta en Dator.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            int players = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Skriv in spelarens namn: ");
                string playersNames = Console.ReadLine();
                AddPlayers(playersNames);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Spelet har börjat!");
            Console.WriteLine();

                foreach (Players name in playerList)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Datorn börjar att kasta... Var god vänta...");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Random rng = new Random();
                    int ranAttempt1 = rng.Next(0, 21);
                    int ranAttempt2 = rng.Next(0, 21);
                    int ranAttempt3 = rng.Next(0, 21);
                    Attempts result = new Attempts(ranAttempt1, ranAttempt2, ranAttempt3);

                    Console.WriteLine("Datorn Fick " + result.GetScore() + " på 3 kast.");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine(name + "s Tur! ");

                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in Poäng mellan 0-20 för kast 1:");
                    int attempt1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in Poäng mellan 0-20 för kast 2:");
                    int attempt2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in Poäng mellan 0-20 för kast 3:");
                    int attempt3 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Attempts result1 = new Attempts(attempt1, attempt2, attempt3);

                    Console.WriteLine(name + " Fick " + result1.GetScore());

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Attempts
    {
        private int attempt1;
        private int attempt2;
        private int attempt3;

        public Attempts(int attempt1 = 0, int attempt2 = 0, int attempt3 = 0)
        {
            this.attempt1 = attempt1;
            this.attempt2 = attempt2;
            this.attempt3 = attempt3;
        }

        public int GetScore()
        {
            return attempt1 + attempt2 + attempt3;
        }
    }
    class Players
    {
        private string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Attempts> attempts = new List<Attempts>();


        public Players(string name = "")
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I need help with creating a while loop around the foreach loop that will end when one of the players has reached a score of 301 or over. I also need a method to keep the score in a List or something like that for every turn. But yeah I'm stuck so any help is greatly appriciated! :)

And sorry if the code is a bit messy

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already have the List for the player's attempts.  You could:

1. add a while loop around the foreach(Players...):
2. append the attempt after it's finished.
3. after a each player's attempts, calculate the total score.
4. print the score and exit if the total score > 301

   ```
   while(true) 
   {

     foreach(Players name in playerList)
     {
       // existing code here

       // you should encapsulate attempts with getter and setter, 
       // but according to your Players class this will work. 
       name.attempts.add(result1); 

       // now sum up the total results for the player
       // exercise for the reader. 
       int totalResults = player.getTotalScore();

       if(totalResults > 301) 
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Player " + name.getName() + " won the game!");
            Environment.exit(0);
        }
     } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just a bit confused as to what I should put in this method: player.getTotalScore();? @Kyle Fransham

Comment: Since you have the list of attempts on the Players object, you can

        int getTottalScore() {
             int sum = 0;
             foreach(Attempts att in attempts) {
                   sum += att.GetScore();
             }
        }
  
to sum up all of the attempts.

Comment: Ah I was thinking in that direction. I have to tinker around a bit it seems.. The code works but the if statement never gets fired for some reason no matter how many points the user gets. The while loop just keeps on going. Thank for your help! It is much appriciated! @Kyle Fransham